# Getting length of each line in a list

Tags: python

I have a block of text and I'd like to add a new line character at the end of any line that is fewer than 50 characters.

This is where I'm at

```
text = open('file.txt','r+')

line_length = []
lines = list(enumerate(text))

for i in lines:
    line_length.append(len(i))

print lines
print line_length
```

I just end up with a large list of the value 2 over and over. I know that the length of each line is not 2.

Edit: Here's the solution I went with

```
text = open('text.txt','r+')
new = open('new.txt','r+')

new.truncate(0)

l=[]

for i in text.readlines():
    if len(i) < 50:
        l.append(i+'\n')
    else:
        l.append(i)

new.write(' '.join(l))

text.close()
new.close()
```

Comment: Don't use `enumerate`, because it's actually appending an `(index, line)` tuple (which has length 2) instead of just a line string.

Comment: Don't use `enumerate`, or if you must get the line-number, do `for i, line in lines: ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well like:

```
text = open('file.txt','r+')
l=[]
for i in text.readlines():
    if len(i)<50:
        l.append(i)
    else:
        l.append(i.rstrip())
```

No need for `enumerate`.

Or one-liner ( i recommend this ):

```
l=[i if len(i)<50 else i.rstrip() for i in text.readlines()]
```

So your code doesn't work because really of `enumerate`.

Both cases:

```
print(l)
```

Is desired output.

Comment: Just to confirm, text.readlines() goes through and separates each lines into its own value and then each instance of the for loop applies those function to that individual line / value.

Answer (score 0):

`lines` is a list of *pairs* (each with a length of two). You need to check the length of the sublist, not the pair that it's in:

```
for i, seq in lines:
  line_length.append(len(seq))
```

Although, as you can see, you don't use `i`, so there's no point in using `enumerate`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are trying to write to a new file, you will want something like this:

```
with open("file.txt", "r+") as input_file, open("output.txt", "w") as output_file:
    for line in input_file:
        if len(line) < 50:
            line += '\n'
        output_file.write(line)
```

The lines in your existing file will often have a newline character at the end of them already, so the result will be two newline characters for lines of length under 50. Use `rstrip` if you need to avoid this.